# How to never have object join a group when hovered and dropped over the latter in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Is there an option to disable to auto-group-join feature? It seems completely undesirable in 99% of all my use-cases. There are always groups somewhere and joining causes all sorts of problems. Constantly holding alt is not a desirable use of the program.